# Putting numbers from a text file into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to put the numbers from the numbers2.txt file into an ArrayList. How would I put the numbers from the file into the ArrayList?
This is what I have so far
I'm new to java so i'm not sure how to store it into an ArrayList
I keep getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10""

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Operator {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Double> array2 = new ArrayList<Double>();


        public void createArrayList()  {

            array.add(add);
            array.add(subtract);
            array.add(multiply);
            array.add(divide);
            array.add(remainder);
            array.add(greaterthan);
            array.add(lessthan);
            array.add(maximum);
            array.add(minimum);
            array.add(power);   
        try {
            FileReader inFile = new FileReader("data/numbers2.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            for (double i = 0; i < array2.size(); i++) 
            {
            array2.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
            System.out.println(array2);
            } 

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, how would I put the numbers from the file into an ArrayList<Double>?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

`String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");` that's a space char inside the split function.

Then use each index of splitLine[] and parse it to double.